# How to solve Cloudformation parameter value greater than 4096 bytes template validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to ingest a json string to aws secrets manager, in my case secret value is very large and it is exceeding 4096 bytes. I have tried using Fn::Join as recommended in the AWS Cloudformation quota documentation for [parameter value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html) but I am still getting the same error "Template format error: Parameter 'SecretKeyValue' default value '****' length is greater than 4096."

Below is cloudformation template I am using, I have split my json into two parameters so that I can join them into single json string to overcome the limitation as mentioned in the documentation.

secretKeyValue1 = {"k1","v1"}
secretKeyValue2 = {"k2","v2"}

Result of secretKeyValue = {"k1", "v1","k2","v2"} // the result will be saved to secrets manager

```
Parameters:
 SecretKeyValue1:
   Description: Specifies Json to use as the secret value for the secret.
   Type: String
   NoEcho: true
 SecretKeyValue2:
   Description: Specifies Json to use as the secret value for the secret.
   Type: String
   NoEcho: true


Resources:

 secrets:
   Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
   Properties:
     TemplateURL: 'Template url'
     Parameters:
       SecretName: "secretName"
       SecretKeyValue: !Join [",", !Split ["},{", !Join [",", [!Ref SecretKeyValue1, !Ref SecretKeyValue2]]]]
//result of secretKeyValue will be saved to the secrets manager.
```

Am I doing this correctly?